# Object doesn't support this property or method at objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0

Tags: methods, properties

Sorry new to scripting and I took over this script and it keeps throwing a "object doesn't support this property or method" at this line in the code `While NOT(objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0)` in windows 7 & IE 11 - used to work in windows XP though.  Full script below any help would be appreciated.  Part of script in question is hilighted with "***"

```
    Sub subGetDatafromuser 'Enter loan and choose app type

sMsg = ""
bContinue = True
x = 2 
iid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,1).Value
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'objIE.Activate

    'Open IE Environment
    With objIE
    .height = 400
    .width = 800
    .menubar = False
    .toolbar = False
    .statusbar = False
   .addressbar = False
    .resizable = False
    .RegisterAsBrowser = True
    .navigate ("about:blank")

    'Load IE
    While(.busy): Wend
End With

Set objIEDoc = objIE.document

'#region Create Form
With objIEDoc
    .Open
    .WriteLn "<html>"
    .WriteLn "<form name = ""form"">"
    .WriteLn "<head>"
    .WriteLn "<title>Please enter a loan number:</title>"
    .WriteLn "    <style>"
           .WriteLn "        body    {font-family:arial; font-size:10pt}"
           .WriteLn "        table    {font-size:9pt; Border-    Collapse:Collapse; width:75%}"
           .WriteLn "        td.ttl    {width:5000px; vertical-align:bottom}"
           .WriteLn "    </style>"
    .WriteLn "<BODY bgcolor=""azure"" style=""font:8pt verdana"">"
    .WriteLn "<table Border=0 style=""font:8pt verdana"">"
    .WriteLn "<cellspacing=""150"">"        
    .WriteLn "<tr align=""center""><td>Loan Number:</td><td><input type=""input"" id=""LnNum"" name=""LnNum"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=100"" maxlength=""10""></tr>"
    .WriteLn "</tr>"
    .WriteLn "<tr>"
    .WriteLn "<td> Please select a loan ID </td>"
    .WriteLn "<td>"
    .WriteLn "<select name = 'sid'>"
    Do until iid = ""

    iid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,1).Value
    docid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,2).Value
        .WriteLN "<Option value = '"&iid&"'>"&iid&" - " &docid&"</option>"
    x = x + 1
    'MsgBox(iid)
    Loop
    .WriteLn "</select>"
     .WriteLn "</td>"
    .WriteLn "<tr>"
    .WriteLn "<td align=""center""><input type=""button"" name = ""formbutton1"" value=""Submit"" id=""Submit"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=75""></td>"
    '.WriteLn "<td align=""center""><input type=""button"" name = ""formbutton2"" value=""Cancel"" id=""Cancel"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=75""></td>"
    .WriteLn "</tr>"
    .WriteLn "</table>"
    .WriteLn "</body>"
    .WriteLn "</html>"
    .WriteLn "    </body>"
    .WriteLn " </form>"
    .WriteLn "</html>"
           .WriteLn "<script language='vbscript'>"
           .WriteLn "    Dim UserDone"
           .WriteLn "    UserDone = 0"
           .WriteLn "    Dim Cancel"
           .WriteLn "    Function formbutton1_OnClick()"
           .WriteLn "        UserDone = 1"
           .WriteLn "    End Function"
           .WriteLn "    Function formbutton2_OnClick()"
           .WriteLn "        UserDone = 2"
           .WriteLn "    "
           .WriteLn "    End Function"
           .WriteLn "    Function GetState()"
           .WriteLn "        GetState = UserDone"
           .WriteLn "    End Function"
           .WriteLn "</script>"
           .Close
    End With

    objIE.Visible = True

***While NOT(objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0)
    Wscript.Sleep 250
Wend***

Do While objIE.Document.script.GetState() > 0 
  sLnNum = objIE.Document.form.LnNum.Value

    sLnNum = Trim(sLnNum)

    Do until Len(sLnNum) >= 10
        sLnNum = "0"&sLnNum
    Loop  

sid = objIE.Document.form.sid.Value

    If sid = null or sid = " " or sid = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a valid document type"
        objIE.Document.script.UserDone = 0
        While NOT(objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0)
                Wscript.Sleep 250
            Wend
    Else
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = nothing
            Set objIEDoc = Nothing
            Call subsavefile
    End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this code! I even knew the developer...sticking HTML where it didn't belong was only one in a long list of eccentricities that have wasted time in my life that I'll never get back...

I know you ended up going with an HTA to solve this issue, but since I had to fix it in another script, I'll share the answer here for posterity.

The problem is that IE11 no longer supports vbscript as a scripting language. I tried using compatibility mode to work as IE7, but no dice. What I ended up doing was converting the script functions into javascript, moving the script into the Header section of the HTML, and then adding an onclick parameter to the buttons to point to the javascript. I think this may work for you:

```
Sub subGetDatafromuser 'Enter loan and choose app type

sMsg = ""
bContinue = True
x = 2 
iid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,1).Value
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    'objIE.Activate

    'Open IE Environment
    With objIE
    .height = 400
    .width = 800
    .menubar = False
    .toolbar = False
    .statusbar = False
    .addressbar = False
    .resizable = False
    .RegisterAsBrowser = True
    .navigate ("about:blank")

    'Load IE
    While(.busy): Wend
End With

Set objIEDoc = objIE.document

'#region Create Form
With objIEDoc
    .Open
    .WriteLn "<html>"
    .WriteLn "<form name = ""form"">"
    .WriteLn "<head>"
    .WriteLn "<script>"
    .WriteLn "var UserDone = 0;"
    .WriteLn "function b1(){UserDone=1;}"
    .WriteLn "function b2(){UserDone=2;}"
    .WriteLn "function GetState(){return UserDone;}"
    .WriteLn "</script>"
    .WriteLn "<title>Please enter a loan number:</title>"
    .WriteLn "<style>"
    .WriteLn " body    {font-family:arial; font-size:10pt}"
    .WriteLn " table    {font-size:9pt; Border-    Collapse:Collapse; width:75%}"
    .WriteLn " td.ttl    {width:5000px; vertical-align:bottom}"
    .WriteLn "</style>"
    .WriteLn "</head>"
    .WriteLn "<BODY bgcolor=""azure"" style=""font:8pt verdana"">"
    .WriteLn "<table Border=0 style=""font:8pt verdana"">"
    .WriteLn "<cellspacing=""150"">"        
    .WriteLn "<tr align=""center""><td>Loan Number:</td><td><input type=""input"" id=""LnNum"" name=""LnNum"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=100"" maxlength=""10""></tr>"
    .WriteLn "</tr>"
    .WriteLn "<tr>"
    .WriteLn "<td> Please select a loan ID </td>"
    .WriteLn "<td>"
    .WriteLn "<select name = 'sid'>"
    Do until iid = ""

    iid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,1).Value
    docid = oExcelSheet.Cells(x,2).Value
        .WriteLN "<Option value = '"&iid&"'>"&iid&" - " &docid&"</option>"
    x = x + 1
    'MsgBox(iid)
    Loop
    .WriteLn "</select>"
    .WriteLn "</td>"
    .WriteLn "<tr>"
    .WriteLn "<td align=""center""><input type=""button"" name = ""formbutton1"" onClick=""javascript:b1()"" value=""Submit"" id=""Submit"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=75""></td>"
    '.WriteLn "<td align=""center""><input type=""button"" name = ""formbutton2"" onClick=""javascript:b2()"" value=""Cancel"" id=""Cancel"" style=""font:8pt verdana; width=75""></td>"
    .WriteLn "</tr>"
    .WriteLn "</table>"
    .WriteLn "</body>"
    .WriteLn "</form>"
    .WriteLn "</html>"
    .Close
    End With

    objIE.Visible = True

While NOT(objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0)
    Wscript.Sleep 250
Wend

Do While objIE.Document.script.GetState() > 0 
  sLnNum = objIE.Document.form.LnNum.Value

    sLnNum = Trim(sLnNum)

    Do until Len(sLnNum) >= 10
        sLnNum = "0"&sLnNum
    Loop  

sid = objIE.Document.form.sid.Value

    If sid = null or sid = " " or sid = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a valid document type"
        objIE.Document.script.UserDone = 0
        While NOT(objIE.Document.script.GetState()>0)
                Wscript.Sleep 250
            Wend
    Else
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = nothing
            Set objIEDoc = Nothing
            Call subsavefile
    End If
Loop


End Sub
```